# httpclient exception "org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection"

Tags: java, exception, httpclient

I am trying to send request to my server, with following code. it failed at 3rd request, always.

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreConnectionPNames;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

public class HttpClientTest {
    private HttpClient client;

    public HttpClientTest() {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 15000);  
        params.setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 15000);

        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "utf-8");
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);
        ThreadSafeClientConnManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager();
        cm.setMaxTotal(100);
        client = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);

        while (true) {
            HttpPost mPost = new HttpPost("http://myip/myservice");

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            try {
                json.put("serialNumber", "abcd");
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            StringEntity s = null;
            try {
                s = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
            s.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
            s.setContentType("application/json");
            mPost.setEntity(s);

            JSONObject response = null;

            System.out.println("HttpClientTest ---> send post");
            HttpResponse mHttpResponse;
            try {
                mHttpResponse = client.execute(mPost);
                System.out.println("HttpClientTest  ---> get response");
                if(mHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                    HttpEntity entity = mHttpResponse.getEntity(); 
                    ContentType contentType = ContentType.getOrDefault(entity);
                    Charset charset = contentType.getCharset();
                    response = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), charset)));

                    System.out.println("HttpClientTest ---> get result:" + response.toString());
                } else {
                    mPost.abort();
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpClientTest t = new HttpClientTest();
    }
}
```

**the exception as following:**

```
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.getEntryBlocking(ConnPoolByRoute.java:417)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute$1.getPoolEntry(ConnPoolByRoute.java:300)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager$1.getConnection(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:224)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:401)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at com.i360r.client.takeaway.network.HttpClientTest.<init>(HttpClientTest.java:68)
    at com.i360r.client.takeaway.network.HttpClientTest.main(HttpClientTest.java:88)
```

Answer (score 86):

I had the same problem and I found the fix.
This timeout is because of a connection leak. In my case, I'm using `httpDelete` method and not consuming the response. Instead, I'm checking the status of the response.

The fix is, the response entity needs to be consumed. In order to ensure the proper release of system resources, one must close the content stream associated with the entity.

So I used  `EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(response.getEntity());` which  ensures that the entity content is fully consumed and the content stream, if exists, is closed.

Comment: Had a similar issue for with the Fluent HTTP Client, when ignoring the response. Still have to call execute().discardContent() to avoid connection leaks.

Comment: So VERY annoying.... The library should discard if you dont consume it... Or at least give you a warning about it...

Comment: What about `response.close()`?

Comment: What if there is an exception and in that case response object will be null? How do we release the connection is such a scenario?

Comment: See other answers below, using a `CloseableHttpClient` and `CloseableHttpResponse` is the preferred approach.

Answer (score 38):

I have fixed it! add `mPost.releaseConnection()` in `finally` blocks.

```
 try {
 } catch (Exception e) {
 } finally {
  mPost.releaseConnection();
 }
```

DO update package `org.apache.httpcomponents` to 4.2.1

Answer (score 13):

Just put the line where you are getting your response inside try-with-resources and use CloseableHttpResponse instead of HttpResponse like this:

```
try(final CloseableHttpResponse mHttpResponse = client.execute(mPost);)
{
 System.out.println("HttpClientTest  ---> get response");
 ....remainder code
```

The mHttpResponse object will be auto consumed and closed for you

Hope this helps!

Comment: The client variable must be an instance of CloseableHttpClient for this to work

Answer (score 6):

Use a `CloseableHttpClient` instead of `HttpClient`. You'll get a `CloseableHttpResponse` instead of a `HttpResponse` which support `close()`. So, when you are done with the response, just close it, no need to close the connection.

```
CloseableHttpResponse response = closableHttpClient.execute(httpPost, context);
```

...do what you need to do with it:

```
response.close();
```

Comment: While this is probably true, it seems like maybe it's intended as a comment on one or more other answers, rather than an answer in its own right, as it doesn't really address the question directly. I'd suggest either editing it to phrase it as an answer to the question, making it a comment on a different answer or creating your own self-answered question, and linking to that in a comment here.

Answer (score 4):

This can also happen if you're using `ApacheHttpClient` with DropWizard 0.6.2, which behind the scenes creates an `MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager` with a default configuration - and that default configuration only allowed 2 concurrent http connections at a time [more info here](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.html#setMaxConnectionsPerHost(int)).

So with this configuration, if your server is getting swamped and making requests to the same host all the time, you'll have max 2 connections allowed running at a time!

Answer (score 4):

We faced the same issue, and we were limited because the connection from pool has initial value of DefaultMaxPerRoute as 2. Ours was an API which would fire different calls with same URI but, different body. Once we set it explicitly to higher value like this

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    cm.setMaxTotal(40);
    cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
```

we were able to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

We were hitting this error when writing and reading parquets via spark.
The exact error was:
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Timeout waiting for connection from pool

We finally figured out that this was related to the upgrade of Hadoop to version 3.1.3
Seems that in this new version the Hadoop, the property name been changed from:
**fs.s3a.connection.maximum**
to:
**spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.maximum**
Renaming the property in our spark configuration, set us back on track.

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same error. It turns out that I needed to close the response.

```
CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
try {
       response = ##some code
} catch(Exception e) {
  if (response != null) {
      response.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess it's better to use try with resource here.

Answer (score 0):

As [Rama](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22822117/524588) said, this could be a sign of a connection leak.

`releaseConnection()` could help resolve this issue but you might need to find out the root cause.

Also, this could happen because there's no available connection you can lease which could happen when you don't have `timeout` config for the `HttpClient`. In this case, `releaseConnection()` wouldn't help.

Comment: What if there is an exception and in that case response object will be null? How do we release the connection is such a scenario if I am not using try with resources?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the bufferedReader that was consuming the entity content stream was not being closed. Closing it resolved the error.