# Connection Pool Timeout Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, connection-pooling

I am using this to setup RestTemplate.
https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/resttemplate/resttemplate-httpclient-java-config/

At first it is working fine, then after sometime I am getting
Timeout waiting for connection from pool; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool

Stacktrace:

> _targethost _targetip _loggername _subsystem _procid _threadid _userid _transactionid _messageid [ERROR] 2021-07-06 15:39:18,396 [http-nio-8080-exec-630] [28477]
> com.thechetankrishna.lookupService:502 - lookup Failed : I/O error on
> POST request for SOME_URL: Timeout waiting for connection from pool;
> nested exception is
> org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting
> for connection from pool

Comment: can you please add the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli
_targethost _targetip _loggername _subsystem _procid _threadid _userid _transactionid _messageid [ERROR] 2021-07-06 15:39:18,396 [http-nio-8080-exec-630] [28477] com.thechetankrishna.lookupService:502 - lookup Failed : I/O error on POST request for http://SOME_URL: Timeout waiting for connection from pool; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool

Comment: `Timeout waiting for connection from pool` all the connections in the pool are in use, it's overloaded or there's a [connection leak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11893328/2834978).

Comment: Actually from what I know RestTemplate already closes the connection once done. If all the connections are in use then also new connection request should wait in a queue ?

Comment: Yes. Look here to [enable logging](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/logging.html) and here is some more info on [how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890024/correct-way-to-implement-http-connection-pooling/50901789#50901789);